# accessing json object with javascript (no var) - dynamically called in file (experiment)

Tags: javascript, json, var, dynamically-generated

I am creating a page which calls dynamic content from the web with javascript and obviously run into a snag with the SOP (same origin policy) I know this would not work on a production page as the calls would need to be checked on the server but I have it at a point where it practically works but I cant access the data. I would really like to know if it is possible.

The code below adds the URL to the file:

```
var url = 'http://theSite.com/?query=' + userInput + '&othercode';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', url);
script.setAttribute('type', "application/json");
script.setAttribute('id', "special");
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
```

This adds the following to my html:

```
<script src="http://theSite.com/?query=userInput&othercode" type="application/json" id="special"></script>
```

Now the problem:
How do I access the resulting data?
I get a JSON script but dont know how to attach it to a variable in Javascript or use it!

the code arrives in this basic format:

```
{"count":5,"results":[{"name":"value","id":"value2", ..... }], ...  "code":200}
```

How do I access the data or assign it to a variable?

(I have not yet tried jQuery and know it will probably be easier but if anyone can help with this code that would be great rather than trying to do this all again in jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have control of the service you're calling (`theSite.com`). One option is to make it return JSONP instead of JSON:

```
dataCallback({"count":5,"results":[{"name":"value","id":"value2", ..... }], ...  "code":200});
```

Or, make your script inside an `iframe` that is served from `theSite.com`, and use `postMessage` to communicate its result back to your window.

Otherwise... well, you're doing exactly what SOP is looking to prevent, so the chances are grim, AFAIK.

Oh, one more option: make an AJAX call to your server, which will make the service call and pass the data to you. Servers are not restricted like clients are.

Comment: Hi Amadan, all good points, in the file I am making I don't have control over theSite.com, also I cant access the server as this is a basic HTML page with Javascript. There is no sever access, I tried AJAX and got the SOP issue which forced the site to: localhost/test/test.html?http://theSite.com/?que... I could make a php script to do the server side code but as I have it to the point where the data is on my page I want to know if there is some way for me to access it. (The code downloads and there are no JS errors).